# Kali Rolling can't connect to external display. How do I troubleshoot it?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, kali-linux

The screen is connected to an HDMI port on my laptop through an adaptor (the screen is not HDMI-capable). The same screen works fine with Windows.

There's a key on my keyboard to change screen, it just says 'No external display'.

How do I troubleshoot this?

```
Linux 4.14.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.14.12-2kali2 (2018-01-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

.

```
 dpkg -l |grep nouv
ii  libdrm-nouveau2:amd64                         2.4.89-1                             amd64        Userspace interface to nouveau-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau                    1:1.0.15-2                           amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
```

.

```
lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth (rev 99)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
```

Comment: Probably the open source driver does not support the external port. You may need to install Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 1):

You can troubleshoot your display setup using the `xrandr` application. When called without arguments, it shows all detected outputs and attached screens with their supported resolutions. Check if there is an output for your HDMI connector, something named `HDMI-X` or `HDMIX` (depending on the configuration, where `X` is a number).

If there is, you should plug in the display and see if `xrandr` shows any supported resolutions below that `HDMI-X` entry. If it shows some, but the screen is not enabled on it's own, try `xrandr --output <output name> --auto` to enable that screen, and `xrandr --output <output name> --left-of <output-name>` to place it to the left of some other output (your Laptop screen for example). `--right-of` works as well.

If there are no screen resolutions visible below the `HDMI-X`-entry, but it still says connected, then your screen (probably because of the adaptor) does not advertise its supported resolutions. In that case, try adding a supported mode manually by using `xrandr`'s `--addmode` switch (see `man xrandr` for further information).

If you can't see either your `HDMI` port or it says `disconnected` despite your screen being plugged in, you'd probably need to fiddle with your hardware/driver configuration. Try proprietary drivers instead of the free ones, as already pointed out in the comments. Try another output if you have multiple, and see if that works.